# how to show contents for notification within a fixed sized window using scroll bar?

Tags: ajax

when there are many contents then the contents are going outside the window box but i want to show all the contents within that box n if there are many contents then a scrollbar will be shown by which i can keep the contents within the box..can anyone help me fixed this?any help would be appreciated.
html page:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //$(document).ready(function()
    //{
        //var hei=$('#notificationsBody').height(); 
    //});


    function myFunction2() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "all_notification.php",
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#notificationsBody').height();

        $("#notification-latest").html(data);
        },
        error: function(){}           
        });
    }
    </script>


    <div id="notificationsBody" style="overflow: auto;height:348px;">
        <div id="notification-latest"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="notificationFooter">
        <a onclick="myFunction2()" href="">See All</a>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean,  $('#notificationsBody').height() gives height of the div. Do you want to show something within notification-latest ?

Comment: notificationsBody is the id of notification box .and to limit the size within the height mentioned in that div,i tried that code in window.document function, actually when there are many contents then the contents are going outside the window box but i want to show the contents within that box with a scrollbar but cant do that..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any java script for this...

just put your html content into another div and give it ***height, width and overflow: scroll;***

```
<div style="height:500px; width: 200px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div id="notificationsBody" style="overflow: auto;height:348px;">
        <div id="notification-latest"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="notificationFooter">
        <a onclick="myFunction2()" href="">See All</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the internal content will not get outside and if overflow then scroll.